# Can we append angular material form fields within a div?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

I have a `div` tag and I want to append the angular material form fields inside that div. The problem is it's not rendering that tags. Can we do this using any method?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGnjx.png)

[image]

Comment: show us what you have already tried.

Comment: Show the code !!

Comment: Please click on the text link above the image, you will see that.

Comment: Why dont you use ngIf instead inject it? do you want to add more than once?

Comment: if you want to add more than one time you can use the ngFor.

Answer (score 1):

The angular way is has an array of object, e,g.

```
data=[{placeholder:"Enter Name",label:"Name"},
      {placeholder:"Enter surname",label:"Surname"}]
```

and make some like

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let item of data">
   <div class="row">
     {{item.label}}<input mat-input [placeholder]="item.placeholder">
   </div>
</mat-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using angular, never manipulate the DOM manually (via native DOM APIs or jQuery).

When you are using a component or a directive in an angular template (ie. the *html* of your component), that is not real html, that is transformed to javascript. So when the application is running, where you wrote `<mat-car>` in you template and you also see `<mat-card>` in the DOM, that was actually put there by the code generated by angular, but a lot other things also happened (ie. the `mat-card` component was initialised).

When you just put the components selector manually into the DOM, nothing will happen, because the component is not initialised. To make it work, you have to use the material components from another components' template. Further reading: https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components

**Suggestion**: don't even import `jQuery` into the project at all, that way you won't even be tempted to do this.